# Java SimpleDateFormat.parse() Error due to DST

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat, dst

We ran into an issue with a job when it tried to use a `SimpleDateFormat.parse(datestr)` call when the `datestr` included times that happened to fall within DST rules (i.e. a `ParseException` happened with `20140309020100` (`yyyyMMddHHmmss`).

I am trying to build code to handle this issue and make it generic to work with all our different formats:

```
public static Date validDateTimestamp(String datetime, String [] formats) 
throws ParseException
{
    for (int inx=0; inx < formats.length; inx++)  
    { 
        try {
          return checkDateFormat(datetime, formats[inx]);

        }
        catch (ParseException e1)
        {
           // ignore this error, just try the next format
        }
    }
// no good date returned using any format, throw an exception
throw new ParseException("bad date: " + datetime, 0);
}
private static Date checkDateFormat(String datetime, String format) 
throws ParseException
{
    SimpleDateFormat sdFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    sdFormat.setLenient(false);
    try {
        return sdFormat.parse(datetime);
     } catch (ParseException e)
     {
        throw e;
     }
}
```

This still has the same issue as before (`ParseException` for `datetime`).

I have tried associating the `SimpleDateFormat` to a `TimeZone`, but that made it so that the returned date was offset by 5 hours.

```
TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
sdFormat.setTimeZone(utc);
```

Is there a way to use a `SimpleDateFormat` to parse a date so that it doesn't change the datetime from what was passed in on the String, will ensure that the date is valid, and also will ignore Daylight Saving Time offsets (i.e. won't throw a `ParseException`)?

We are not looking to add any new libraries to the project, but to get it working with the standard Java classes.

---

Based on the answer from @GriffeyDog.....

The `Date` object returned from the `SimpleDateFormat.parse()` call will be in the timezone of  where it is run. In my case, EDT. Even setting the timezone of the `SimpleDateFormat` will not help with that - other than the fact that it will parse what was a bad datetimestamp for EDT; what will get into the Date object will be converted to local time. Since changing the JVM settings for this are not a viable option (shared servers), instead I modified the code as follows:

- Have both methods return a `String` value
- Modify `checkDateFormat` so that instead of returning `sdFormat.parse(datetime)` it assigns that to a `Date` object
- Set a new format to standardize a date return `String` - `yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss`
- Use that format to return a `String` of the date - `sdFormat.format(date)`
- Modify the Oracle calls that did something with the date to use Oracle's `to_date()` function instead of relying on conversion of a `Date` object

This seems to do what we want. `20140309020500` will now be allowed as a valid date.

Comment: Since `20140309020100` isn't a valid date/time in your local timezone, what would you expect the returned `Date` value from your method to be?

Comment: @GriffeyDog - we want the method to accept the date as valid.  Just because the US has DST, doesn't mean that it is invalid. However, changing the `TimeZone` also changes the original value to include an offset.

Comment: But you are returning a `Date` object, which represents an exact number of milliseconds since 1/1/1970 00:00 UTC. How can `SimpleDateFormat#parse` give you such a `Date` object if you're not providing it with a valid date/time? In order to convert your date/time string into a `Date`, `SimpleDateFormat` needs a time zone to work with. It will use your default locale's time zone if you don't provide it with one. And in your default time zone, DST exists, and you are not providing a valid date/time string for those considerations.

Comment: @GriffeyDog what I ended up doing is changing the methods to return a `String` value (since the `Date` object that got set would always report the value with an offset). I modified the code to use the `UTC` timezone, and used a `SimpleDateFormat.format()` call to report the Date in the `UTC` timezone.  This allowed `20140309 02:01` to now pass. I then update the Oracle calls to use the `to_date` function on the `String`. Probably cleaner overall. If you want to put something like this in an answer, I will give you credit. Thanks.

Comment: @Ruminator Mention your time zone, to help explore the Daylight Saving Time issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning a `Date` object, which represents an exact number of milliseconds since 1/1/1970 00:00 UTC. A `SimpleDateFormat#parse` cannot give you such a `Date` object if you're not providing it with a valid date/time. In order to convert your date/time string into a `Date`, `SimpleDateFormat` needs a time zone to work with. It will use your default locale's time zone if you don't provide it with one. And in your default time zone, DST exists, and you are not providing a valid date/time string for those considerations.